# Создать Frame в зависимости от назначения кнопки

Tags: delphi

На форме:
 * TCategoryButtons (в нем например 3 категории в каждой из которых по 10 кнопок)
 * TPageControl (чистый)
Создано 30 (например) различных фреймов.

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку:
1. Проверить не создан ли уже фрейм (для одной кнопки только один фрейм).
2. Создать вкладку в TPageControl и активировать ее.
3. Создать соответствующий кнопке фрейм и положить его в созданную вкладку(если закрывается вкладка, убить и фрейм).

Вот что смог сделать, но вешать это на каждую кнопку... Сомнительная затея.

```
procedure TForm1.CategoryButtons1Categories0Items0Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Client: TTabSheet;
begin
  if (not Assigned(Frame2)) then
  begin
    Client := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
    Client.PageControl := PageControl1;
    Client.Caption := CategoryButtons1.Categories[0].Items[0].Caption;
    PageControl1.ActivePage := Client;

    Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(nil);
    Frame2.Parent := Client;
  end;
end;
```

Потому прошу помощи!

Пробовал сделать вот таким способом:

```
type
  TFrameClass = class of tframe; 

function GetFrClass(const aClassID: Integer): TFrameClass;
begin
  case aClassID of
    1:
      Result := TFrame2;
    2:
      Result := TFrame3;
  else
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateFrm(tags: Integer; NameTSh: string);
var
  FrClass: TFrameClass;
  Frame: tframe;
  Client: TTabSheet;
begin
  FrClass := GetFrameClass(tags);

  if (FrClass <> nil) then
  begin
    Client := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
    Client.PageControl := PageControl1;
    Client.Caption := NameTSh;

    Frame := FrClass.Create(Client);
    Frame.Parent := Client;
  end;
end;
```

Но такой способ не ограничивает количество создаваемых экземпляров фрейма.

Comment: Что мешает вместо Frame1, Frame2... сделать `Frames: array [0..29] of TFrame;`, далее каждой кнопке назначить `Tag` от 0 до 29 и использовать его как индекс фрейма в массиве?

Comment: сохраняйте ссылки на фреймы при создании. и удаляйте при закрытии. Можно сделать класс типизорованный от класса фрейма, и чтобы он реализовывал синглтон/фабрику при создании. Второй ваш подход доработайте немого да и все.

Comment: @teran вот знал бы я, как это сделать

Comment: @Alekcvp я думал об этом, но что-то не придумал как применить это (ведь мне их еще и закрывать необходимо когда не нужны)

Comment: @idrees, когда закрываете - записываете в массив nil, что там сложного?

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите вариант использования RTTI для аннотирования и привязки фреймов к тегам.
Например, заведите новый юнит, какой-нибудь `FrameRegistry`. И опишите там кастомный атрибут, который свяжет ваш фрейм со значением тэга:

```
  FrameTagAttribute = class ( TCustomAttribute)
     private
       FTag : integer;
    public
      constructor Create(tag : integer);
      property Tag : integer read FTag;
  end;
```

Подключите юнит к классам фреймов, и подпишите свои фреймы, как-то так

```
[FrameTag(1)]
TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
  .....

[FrameTag(2)]
TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
   ....
```

*Не буду пояснять про то как написать конструктор класса-атрибута, в целом это и так очевидно, но и можно прочитать в [документации](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declaring_Custom_Attributes_(RTTI)).*

Теперь, реализуйте простой класс "реестра фреймов", в котором будем сохранять связи тэгов и классов фреймов. В целом это будет обычный словарь с небольшой оберткой:

```
  TFrameRegistry = class(TObject)
    private
      class var FRegistry : TDictionary<integer, TFrameClass>;
    public
      class constructor Create();
      class procedure add(fc : TFrameClass);
      class function get(tag: integer):TFrameClass;
  end;
```

в класс-конструкторе, очевидно, создаем словарь, а деструктор надо дописать.

Если рассмотреть метод `add` для регистрации фрейма, то он на вход должен получить класс фрейма, взять его атрибут `FrameTag` и занести в словарь:

```
class procedure TFrameRegistry.add(fc : TFrameClass);
var ctx : TRttiContext;
    t : TRttiType;
    a : TCustomAttribute;
begin
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
    try
        t := ctx.GetType(fc);
        for a in t.GetAttributes() do begin
            if a is FrameTagAttribute then begin
                FRegistry.Add( FrameTagAttribute(a).Tag, fc);
                break;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        ctx.Free();
    end;
end;
```

Немного забегая вперед, сразу метод возврата класса по тэгу, впрочем очевидный:

```
class function TFrameRegistry.get(tag: integer): TFrameClass;
begin
    result := FRegistry[tag];
end;
```

Далее, следует непосредственно вызвать регистрацию фреймов. Сделать это, конечно же, проще всего в секции `initialization` юнитов всех используемых фреймов:

```
initialization
   TFrameRegistry.add(TFrame2);
```

И возвращаясь непосредственно в главный юнит, тут практически остается ваш код:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateFrameButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var tag : integer;
    tab : TTabSheet;
    fc : TFrameClass;
    f : TFrame;
begin
    tag := TControl(sender).tag;

    if not FFrames.ContainsKey(tag) then begin
        tab := TTabSheet.Create(self);
        tab.PageControl := FramesPageControl;
        tab.Caption := Format('frame %d', [tag]);

        fc := TFrameRegistry.Get(tag);
        if not assigned(fc) then begin
            raise Exception.Create('unkonow frame tag');
        end;

        f := fc.Create(tab);
        f.parent := tab;
        FFrames.Add(tag, f);
    end;

end;
```

где `FFrames : TDictionary<integer, TFrame>` - словарь, хранящий ссылки на экземпляры созданных фреймов.

Время жизни фрейма контролируется табом, поскольку он указывается как `owner` при создании. При закрытии таба потребуется убирать ссылку из словаря. В целом сложности нет никакой, вариантов реализации тоже можно придумать несколько.

В общем итоге, для расширения списка используемых фреймов вам каждый раз надо будет аннотировать фрейм атрибутом, и подключать регистрацию в секции инициализации. То есть в каждый юнит фрейма добавлять 2 строки кода.

---

В целом все это может показаться несколько громоздким, но вызвано это тем, что вы используете `CategoryButtons`. При добавлении новой кнопки она не является членом класса формы. Если бы мы работали с отдельными, например, `TButton` на форме, то могли бы просто аннотировать каждую кнопку, подписав, какой фрейм она должна создавать:

```
TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ....
  [FrameClass(TFrame1)]  
  button1 : TButton;
```

и тогда даже тэгов не понадобилось бы, просто прописали бы атрибут к каждой кнопки и все, дело бы осталось за одним вытаскивания атрибута для нажатой кнопки. Примерно так:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateFrameButtonClick2(Sender: TObject);

    function GetFrameClass(name: string):TFrameClass;
    var ctx : TRttiContext;
        f : TRttiField;
        a : TCustomAttribute;
    begin
        ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
        try
            f := ctx.GetType(self.ClassType).getField(name);
            for a in f.GetAttributes() do begin
                if a is FRameClassAttribute then begin
                    exit(  FrameClassAttribute(a).FrameClass );
                end;
            end;

        finally
            ctx.free();
        end;
        result := nil;
    end;


var fc : TFrameClass;
begin
    fc := GetFrameClass( TControl(sender).name );
    if assigned(fc) then begin
        ShowMessage( fc.ClassName );
    end;

end;
```

---

*зы: код для ХЕ2*